# complex simplification of $y''+4y'+13y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

My textbook uses $y’’ + 4y’ + 13y = 0$ as an example in its constant coefficient homogenous 2nd order ode.

The textbook uses $p(r)$ and the quadratic formula to separate these types of equations into three categories. This particular example uses complex roots $r_1 = -2-3i$ and $r_2 = -2+3i$.

It is perfectly reasonable to say that the solution to this is $y_1 = e^{(-2-3i)x}$ and $y_2 = e^{(-2+3i)x}$.

Therefore $y=c_1 e^{(-2-3i)x}+c_2 e^{(-2+3i)x}$.

My book doesn't go into Euler's formula to solve this particular example and the method it uses seems fairly long winded to get to

$$y=e^{-2x}\bigl(k_1 \cos(3x)+k_2 \sin(3x)\bigr),$$

which looks like Euler’s identity, but when I try to rearrange the terms I get

$$\begin{align} 
y &= c_1 e^{-2x}\bigl(\cos(-3x)+i\sin(-3x)\bigr)+c_2e^{-2x}\bigl(\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)\bigr) \\
&= e^{-2x}\Bigl(c_1\bigl(\cos(-3x)+i\sin(-3x)\bigr)+c_2\bigl(\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)\bigr)\Bigr) \\
&= e^{-2x}\Bigl(c_1\bigl(\cos(3x)-i\sin(3x)\bigr)+c_2\bigl(\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)\bigr)\Bigr) \\
&= e^{-2x}\bigl(c_1\cos(3x)-i c_1\sin(3x)+c_2\cos(3x)+i c_2\sin(3x)\bigr) \\
&= e^{-2x}\bigl( (c_1+c_2)\cos(3x)+i(c_2-c_1)\sin(3x)\bigr).
\end{align}
$$

Let $c_1+c_2=k_1$, $c_2-c_1=k_2$. Then
$$y =e^{-2x}\bigl(k_1\cos(3x)+ik_2\sin(3x)\bigr).$$

Is this me doing the algebra wrong or is $k_2$ allowed to be an imaginary number?

Comment: $k_2$ is allowed to be imaginary when we look at this as acting in $\mathbb{C}$,  then we get two linearly independent functions that live in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Or you could just set $k_2=i(c_2-c_1)$, as $c_1,c_2$ certainly are allowed to be complex coefficients for the complex-valued basis functions. Note that having a real solution $y=\bar y$ would also impose strict condition on the first solution form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

As $y$ should be real, we have

$$
y = e^{-ax}(c_1 e^{-b x i}+c_2e^{b x i})= \bar y = e^{-ax}(\bar c_1 e^{b x i}+\bar c_2e^{-b x i})
$$

or $c_1 = \bar c_2, \ c_2 = \bar c_1$. This agrees with the fact that the solution for $y’’ + 4y’ + 13y = 0$ requires two generic constants and nor four as in $c_1, c_2$. Now if we use the Euler's identity with those found relationships we will get to the correct result.

NOTE

In your final result, as $c_1 = \bar c_2, \ c_2 = \bar c_1$ we have $\{k_1, i k_2\}\in \mathbb{R}$